# Setting request header in $.ajax

Tags: .htaccess, jquery, xmlhttprequest, authorization

I need to make a request to a site which has HT Access enable. The str below has the username:password

Below is the code I am using

```
var str='msft:sks*';
var bytes = Crypto.charenc.Binary.stringToBytes(str);
var base64 = Crypto.util.bytesToBase64(bytes);
var auth='BASIC '+base64;           
$.ajax({
    url : 'http://mft.sta.com/',
    method : 'GET',
    async:false,
    beforeSend : function(req,settings) {           
        req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', auth);
    }
});
```

I am getting 401 authentication required error in FireBug.

But when i tried in POSTER plugin I am able to get the response. I copied the value of 'auth' in the above function and set it in the requester header for the key 'Authorization' in POSTER and it is working like a charm. But failing in Firefox or IE.

Any possible solution or workarounds.

Thanks in Advance.